# Directional derivative, gradient and metric

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-spaces, tensors

Considering the general expression of gradient with the directional derivative operator on $f$ function along $\vec{v}$ vector :

$$df(v)=\langle\text{grad}(f),v\rangle = g^{ij}\partial_{i} f v_{j}=\partial_{i} f v^{i}$$

taking $\partial_{i} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ (with $x^{i}$ contravariant coordinates).

Can I write also :

$$df(v)=\langle\text{grad}(f),v\rangle = \partial^{i} f v_{i}$$

with $\partial^{i} = g^{ij} \partial_{j} =\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ where $x_{i}$ are covariant coordinates ??

i.e, I don't know if I can raise up the index of $\partial_{j}$ multiplying it by $g^{ij}$ while defining $\partial^{i} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$ ?

Regards

**UPADTE 1** : it may be that I do confusions between covariant/contravariant coordinates of a vector and curvilinear coordinates (curviliear coordinates don't have covariant/contravariants properties)

**UPDATE 2** : I am stucked on the following expression :

$$\vec{e_{i}}=g_{ij}\vec{e^{j}} = \partial_{i}=g_{ij} \partial^{j} = = g_{ij}dx^{j} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} dx^{j} \neq \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\quad(1)$$

In the same time, I can write :

$$\vec{e_{i}}=g_{ij}\vec{e^{j}}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} dx^{j}=\delta_{ij} \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\quad(2)$$

What's one of these two above expressions, (1) and (2), is correct ?

The main issue is that I don't know if I can express the basis vector $\vec{e_{i}}$ as a linear combination of 1-forms $\vec{e^{i}}=\partial/\partial x^{i}$ (dual basis vectors) : at first sight, it doesn't make any sense. Anyone could help me with this contradiction ?

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "covariant coordinates."

Comment: -@TedShifrin indeed, this is the confusion I do, one says "contravariant/covariant" coordinates for a vector but for curvilinear coordinates, can we distinguish $\partial^{i}$ and $\partial_{i}$ by considering $\partial_{i} = (g^{ij})^{-1}\partial^{j}$ and introducing a pseudo "covariant curvilinear coordinates" $x_{i}$ ?, i.e can one find a way to check or define a coordinate "$x_{i}$" that could allow to write : $\partial^{i} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_{i}}$, I hope I am clear.

Comment: Your conventions are quite confusing. Usually, when one distinguishes between covariant and contravariant components, writes indices for vector components up ($v^i $) and indices for vectors themselves down ($\partial_i $). Of course you can change the criterion, but be consecuent. If you write $v_i$ for vector components then $\partial/\partial x^i $ must be denote as $\partial^i$.

Comment: -@Dog_69 . So, can I have a relation between basis and dual basis vectors, i.e a type of relation like : $\vec{e_{i}}=g_{ij}\vec{e^{j}} = \partial_{i}=g_{ij} \partial^{j} = = g_{ij}dx^{j} = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} dx^{j} \neq \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ since I have with Einstein summing convention : $\vec{e_{i}}=\sum_{j=1}^{n}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} dx^{j} \neq \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}}$ ? any clarification is welcome

Comment: Well, the problem I see here is that $g_{ij}dx^j$ is a linear combination of 1-forms and hence just a 1-form. I mean, you can rise and down indices, but you have to be cautious. It is true the metric induces a bundle isomorphism $\phi_g:TM\rightarrow T^M$. This map takes a vector $X$ and gives you a 1-form $\alpha=\Phi_g(X)$ which in components can be express as $\alpha_i=g_{ij}X^j$. This is the operation of downing indices. With the inverse map $\phi_g^{-1}$ you can rise the indices of a 1-form $\alpha$: $X=\phi_g^{-1}(\alpha)$; $X^i = g^{ij}\alpha_j$. But this is different than $g_{ij}dx^j$.

Comment: -@Dog_69 thanks for your answer. What's the link between "bundle isomorphism $\phi_{g}$" and the action of $dx^{j}$ dual vector on a vector $X$ with : $\vec{X}\,dx^{j}= X^{i}(\partial/\partial x^{i})\,dx^{j} = X^{i} \delta_{ij} = X^{j}$ ?

Comment: I don't understand your answer very well. May you explain me a little bit what is the meaning of $\vec{X} dx^j$, please?

Comment: -@Dog_69 $\vec{X}\,dx^{j}= X^{i}(\partial/\partial x^{i})\,dx^{j}$ is the action of $dx^{i}$ 1-form on vector $\vec{X}$ or if you prefer the inner product beween $\vec{X}$ vector (expressed into $\vec{e_{i}}=\partial/\partial x^{i}$ basis) and the dual basis vector $\vec{e^{i}}=dx^{i}$ : this scalar product gives the contravariant component $X^{i}$ of vector $\vec{X}$, is it clearer ? regards

Comment: Oh, yes. Humm, the relation is the following: as you have said perfectly, the action of $dx^j$ over any vector field $X$ gives you the $j$-th component of the vector. Now we study the action of the 1-form $\alpha= phi_g(\partial_j)$. In coordinates, $$\alpha_i = g_ik(\partial_j)^k = g_ik\delta_j^k = g_{ij}.$$ And now, $\alpha(X) = \alpha_i X^i= g_ijX^i$. So, while the 1-form $dx^j$ gives you only the $j$-th component, the 1-form $\alpha^j$ (I have added a superscript because it comes from $\partial_k$ gives you the dor product between the $j$-th column of $g$ and $X$...

Comment: ... Notice that when $g_{ij}= \delta_{ij}$ the dual basis $\{dx^j\}$ and the metric basis (i.e. the basis obtained by downing the indices of the vectors $\partial_j$) are the same (for example in $\mathbb R^3$). In this cases is very difficult to distinguish between covariant and contravariant components because their numeric value is the same: $X_i=X^i$. And I think this is the reason why the gradient of a function and the exterior derivative are confused sometimes.

Comment: -@Dog_69 . In your expression : $\alpha_{i} = g_{ik}(\partial_j)^{k} = g_{ik}\delta_{j}^{k} = g_{ij}$, you want to say, with your notations, that $(\partial_j)^k = (\partial_j).dx^{k} = \delta_{j}^{k}$ ,i.e the $k-th$ contravariant component of vector $\partial_{i}$, isn't it ?

Comment: Yes. That was exactly what I wanted to mean.

Comment: -@Dog_69. It seems that $(\partial_j)^k = (\partial_j).dx^{k} = \delta_{j}^{k}$ is just the definition of relation between basis vectors $\partial_{i}$ and dual vector basis $dx^{k}$. And what do you think about my **UPDATE 2** ?, i.e if I can express the classical basis vectors ($\vec{e_{i}}=\partial/\partial x^{i}$) as a linear combination function of dual basis vector (1-form : $\vec{e^{i}}=dx^{i}$) and vice versa ?

Comment: For your update 2 I recommend you these two Wiki articles: [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raising_and_lowering_indices) and [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Musical_isomorphism). The problem you have is that you want to write a vector as a linear combination of 1-forms, which is completely impossible, since they belong to different spaces. Don't be confused: even when the logical operation for lowering the index to $dx^j$ is $g_ijdx^j$ this is not a vector, but a 1-form.